# Bash function: Is there a way to check if a variable was defined locally?

Tags: bash

Suppose that you have a function with a lot of options and that you decide to store their value dynamically:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
fun() {
    local OPTIND __option

    while getopts ":$(printf '%s:' {a..z} {A..Z})" __option
    do
        case $__option in
        [[:alpha:]])
            # ... 
            local "__$__option=$OPTARG"
        esac
    done

    # here you might get a conflict with external variables:
    [[ ${__a:+1} ]] && echo "option a is set"
    [[ ${__b:+1} ]] && echo "option b is set"
    # etc...
    [[ ${__Z:+1} ]] && echo "option Z is set"
}
```

Is there a way to check if a variable was defined locally?

Comment: From the `bash` manual: _With no operands, `local` writes a list of local variables to  the standard output._

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can definitely detect a variable is local (if it has been declared with one of Bash's `declare`, `local`, `typeset` statements).

Here is an illustration:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

a=3
b=2

fn() {
  declare a=1
  b=7
  if local -p a >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    printf 'a is local with value %s\n' "$a"
  else
    printf 'a is not local with value %s\n' "$a"
  fi
  if local -p b >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    printf 'b is local with value %s\n' "$b"
  else
    printf 'b is not local with value %s\n' "$b"
  fi
}


fn
```

Output is:

```
a is local with value 1
b is not local with value 7
```

Comment: I saved your script in `test.sh`, and run `./test.sh`, but got `b is local with value `. Something weird is going on. I think this is not a reliable way to test if a variable is local or not. My bash version is `5.0.17(1)-release`

Comment: @Philippe I think it may be a bug or different compile setting in 5.0.17. I have no issue with 5.1.8(1)-release. If the script tells you that b is local, then b is local. Verify it with printing the value of b in global scope after running the function. if after the function b=2 again, then b was really local to the function

Comment: I have just tested with version 3.2.7 and 4.4, again they say b is local. Only version 5.1.4/MacOS says `b is not local with value 7`. So I would say it's a bug (or "new feature") of 5.1.

Comment: Looks like `local -p` is Bash>5.0. Unfortenately local is not a var attribute either, so the only way to check with Bash<=5.0 is to do so before local declaration, or parse the output of a plain `local` invocation.

Comment: I don't think the above works in all cases: It seems `local -p` shows only those variables that are declared `local` **at the current function**. If this function was however called by another function and that made the same variable `local`, then it is still `local` in the current function - with respect to the calling function, in the sense that one doesn't see an outermore or global version.